# ingested data is not getting typed correctly as my location field is not being set to geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, logstash

I have been ingesting documents, and I have a field called *location*.  I keep trying to set it to a geo_point but it keeps saying next to the field name "[T]" which i presume means text, even though it is a array of floats representing [lat,lon].

In my Kibana instance, I went to template management for my index, and attempted to create a new property in the Mappings section for the property *location* and set it as a geo_point..  Afterwards I delete the index so it repopulates. When I look at the Mappings for the index I see:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "true",
      "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "*"
        ],
        "excludes": []
      },
      "dynamic_date_formats": [
        "strict_date_optional_time",
        "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z",
        "yyyymmdd'T'HH:mm"
      ],
      "date_detection": true,
      "numeric_detection": false,
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "ignore_malformed": false
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "bustime-response": {
          "properties": {
            "error": {
              "properties": {
                "msg": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "rt": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "vehicle": {
              "type": "object"
            }
          }
        },
        "des": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "dly": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "hdg": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "lat": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "location-map": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "lon": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "mode": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "origtatripno": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "pdist": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "pid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "psgld": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "rt": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "rtpidatafeed": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "spd": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "tablockid": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "tatripid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "tmstmp": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "vid": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "zone": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see above that it shows the object and the type but when I ingest the information it doesnt seem to take and it doesnt log it as geospatial data.

- My Index name is:  transit-[DATE]
- My Index Template is applied to: transit-*

Below is the index template I have, which is mostly created from Kibana

```
PUT _index_template/transit-template
{
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "lifecycle": {
          "name": "logstash-policy",
          "rollover_alias": "logstash"
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "refresh_interval": "5s"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_routing": {
        "required": false
      },
      "numeric_detection": false,
      "dynamic_date_formats": [
        "strict_date_optional_time",
        "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z",
        "yyyymmdd'T'HH:mm"
      ],
      "dynamic": true,
      "_source": {
        "excludes": [],
        "includes": [
          "*"
        ],
        "enabled": true
      },
      "date_detection": true,
      "properties": {
        "location-map": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "@timestamp": {
          "index": true,
          "ignore_malformed": false,
          "store": false,
          "type": "date",
          "doc_values": true
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "index_patterns": [
    "transit-*"
  ],
  "composed_of": []
}
```

In case it is an issue with my Logstash config file, I will attach that in case somehow I am ingesting incorrectly.

```
    input {
      http_poller {
        urls => {
          url1 => ""
        }
        schedule => {
          every => "2m"
        }
        codec => "json"
      }
    }
    
    filter {
      split {
        field => "[bustime-response][vehicle]"
      }
      mutate {
        rename => {
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][vid]" => "vid"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][rtpidatafeed]" => "rtpidatafeed"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][tmstmp]" => "tmstmp"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][lat]" => "lat"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][lon]" => "lon"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][hdg]" => "hdg"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][pid]" => "pid"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][rt]" => "rt"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][des]" => "des"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][pdist]" => "pdist"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][dly]" => "dly"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][spd]" => "spd"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][tatripid]" => "tatripid"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][origtatripno]" => "origtatripno"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][tablockid]" => "tablockid"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][zone]" => "zone"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][mode]" => "mode"
          "[bustime-response][vehicle][psgld]" => "psgld"
        }
      }
      mutate {
        add_field => { "location" => ["%{[lat]}","%{[lon]}"] }
        add_field => { "[location-map][lat]" => "%{lat}" }
        add_field => { "[location-map][lon]" => "%{lon}" }
      }
      mutate {
        convert => {
          "location" => "float"
          "[location-map][lat]" => "float"
          "[location-map][lon]" => "float"
          "pid" => "integer"
          "pdist" => "integer"
          "spd" => "integer"
          "tatripid" => "integer"
          "vid" => "integer"
          "lat" => "float"
          "lon" => "float"
          "origtatripno" => "integer"
        }
      }
    }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "${ES_HOSTS}" ]
        user => "${ES_USER}"
        password => "${ES_PASSWORD}"
        cacert => '/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt'
        index => "transit-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After ensuring that all of this is properly ingested, you would need to manage your index and then refresh it.  Therefore, all the geo_spacial data would be applied from your templates.